# What kind of coordinate notation is this?

Tags: coordinate-system, belgium

I've tried searching the web and a lot of questions here to find out which coordinate system this is:
[ 4.402223, 51.228429 ]

It should be near Antwerpen.

Does anyone recognise what coordinate system it is?

Comment: Have you looked into decimal degrees and where they would place that point?

Comment: Sure looks like decimal degrees in X,Y (lon,lat) order.

Comment: try https://www.google.com/maps/@51.228429,4.3693928,13z

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.